Asus vivobook dual boot installation
I have 13th Gen Intel core i3-1315U Asus vivobook laptop I want to install Ubuntu alongside windows 11 but even after disabling secure boot it does not make me dual boot and gives warning "invalid signature detected check secure boot policy in Setup" .how can I make dual boot.It is not letting me boot through USB

Please edit the question and include way more details. The version of Ubuntu being used. The exact steps you are taking. The full text of the error message. Was the installation complete? That is a start.

Which bios interface you used? UEFI interface or MyASUS in UEFI?

First of all you need to reboot in a right way from Window 11 to unlock disks for manipulations:

Click on Windows Start menu > select Settings.
Find System menu > Recovery > under Advanced startup select Restart now.

After that you can use USB Drive to install your Linux OS.

I have the same Laptop, I use Windows for my personal use, and Linux for studying.
Here is what I did:

Make sure to disable Bit encryption in windows before procceding.
Go to the start menu and click on the restart button while pressing shift.
Go to the recovery options and click on the button with UEFI frimware something, press F8 and choose your USB stick.
When the Ubuntu setup starts fill the necessry fields as you like. When you reach the step where it asks you to choose the disk, you will be presented with 3 options, first to install Ubuntu alongside Windows, second erase the disk and install Ubuntu, third enter partioning setup. Choose the first one, and let Ubuntu setup do it is job. And you're done.

